Utiliser "que" en pronom sans antécédent ?
Dans le paragraphe suivant, extrait de l'"Esprit des Lois" de Montesquieu, je me suis arrêté pour une interrogation sur la fonction grammaticale de l’élément en gras.
L'amour de la frugalité borne le désir d'avoir à l'attention que demande le nécessaire pour sa famille et même le superflu pour sa patrie.
"Que" semble avoir le sens de la locution conjonctive "ce que" même s'il manque l'antécédent. Le wiktionnaire comporte une entrée consacrant l'usage dans des tours figés, mais dont le paragraphe  précité  ne fait pas partie.
Ai-je peut-être mal appréhendé le sens de ce pronom ?
Connaissez-vous des références encyclopédiques traitant de ce cas d'usage ?
Merci d'avance !
NB: Dans l'encyclopédie publiée en 1777, la citation/interprétation du texte de Montesquieu figure avec une légère différence par rapport au texte original de l'auteur :

... dit l'auteur de l'esprit des lois ...
L'amour de la frugalité bornant le désir d'avoir, à l'attention que
demande le nécessaire pour sa famille, réserve le superflu pour le bien de la patrie
... ajoute M. de Montesquieu ...

.

« ce que » n'est pas une locution conjonctive mais un pronom : https://francais.lingolia.com/fr/grammaire/les-pronoms/pronoms-relatifs

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paragraphe+pr%C3%A9cit%C3%A9%2Cpr%C3%A9cit%C3%A9+paragraphe&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3

Pouvez-vous préciser où cela se trouve dans L'Esprit des Lois?

@Frank Chapitre 3. C'est un pronom relatif comme tu l'as dit dans ta réponse effacée.

@Graffito Tu ne donnes pas une citation mais un commentaire de la citation.  Ce n'est pas la même chose, la façon dont tu le présentes semble signifier que tu cites les mots de Montesquieu dans l'Esprit des Lois.   La citation donnée par le PO est bien celle du texte de Montesquieu. Outre lien ci-dessus  (oublié donné le livre pour Frank, c'est le V ) et édition de 1749. Mais il ne m'appartient de modifié ton edit.

@None c'est justement parce que la "citation" n'est pas la reproduction exacte du texte de Montesquieu que je l'ai indiquée afin d'apporter un autre éclairage sur la phrase. J'ai modifié mon edit pour tenir compte de ton commentaire.

@Graffito Je maintiens que dans l'encyclopédie ce n'est pas une citation (« Action de citer un passage d'auteur, de reproduire exactement ce qu'il a dit ou écrit, oralement ou dans un texte ». (TLF, c'est moi qui souligne), c'est une interprétation.

@None Dans de nombreuses définitions du mot "citation" (ou de "citer"), la notion d'exactitude n'apparaît pas explicitement, Par exemple, dans le Larousse, citation = Action de citer, de rapporter les mots ou les phrases de quelqu'un ; paroles, passage empruntés à un auteur ou à quelqu'un qui fait autorité.

« Avoir à l'attention » n'est pas une expression ; la phrase se décompose comme suit.

L'amour de la frugalité : S
borne : V
le désir d'avoir  : COD, (c'est à dire « le désir de posséder des choses »)
à l'attention  : COI

L'antécédent du pronom « que » est « attention ».

L'amour de la frugalité borne le désir d'avoir à l'attention que demande le nécessaire pour sa famille et même le superflu pour sa patrie.

Ce qui est dit revient à ceci, le style en moins :  l'amour de la frugalité borne  le désir de posséder au soin de pourvoir sa famille du nécessaire,  et borne même le superflu pour sa patrie.

Raison du vote négatif ? Aucune ?

Pas mon dv mais peut-être, malgré ton avertissement, est-ce l'expression est la cause pour limiter.

@jlliagre En tout cas je ne trouve pas non plus  que « cause pour limiter » soit du trop bon français.

la cause à la base de la limitation du désir que non plus.

@Frank Après ceci, «Un tel jugement suppose une conception "primitive" de la cause à la base de la divination augurale ou tout au moins des dirae, dont Cicéron nous dit pourtant … Conceptions latines du sens et de la signification: colloque ... - Marc Baratin, ‎Claude Moussy · 1999, je vais m'en tenir à ma correction, mais n'hésitez pas à proposer d'autres options (si ça vous intéresse).

Verbeux avec deux compléments de nom empilés l'un sur l'autre. Et puis cause et base sont un peu la même chose.

@Frank En effet, ce n'est pas aussi direct que « cause de la limitation » ou « base de la limitation », mais c'est une formule qui semble insister sur le fait que la cause n'est pas la goutte d'eau qui fait déborder le vase, mais qu'elle serait la cause fondamentale.

Mon edit tentait de coller au sens de L'esprit des lois. La citation qu'en fait l'Encyclopédie déforme ce sens. Pour coller à l'Encyclopédie, il faut à mon avis "et réserve" au lieu de "et borne même".

C'est le pronom relatif que, dont l'antécédent est ici attention.
